# Dell 1850 What version ESX can I use?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, dell, dell-poweredge

What version of ESX can I run on dell 1850? I have a chance to build a test lab with four 1850 servers and would like to run the latest version if I can.

Thanks

Knothead00

Answer (score 2):

You can start with the [VMWare Hardware Compatability Search](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php) webpage:

Or you could ask us to do the work for you. The link below takes you to the actual 1850 results:

http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=server&partner=23&keyword=1850&page=1&display_interval=10&sortColumn=Partner&sortOrder=Asc

Basically, depending on your CPU that you have in there, you can go up to either 3.5U4 or 4.1U3

Either of those versions are a bit behind. ESX/ESXi 3.5 is already end of life and ESX/ESXi 4.1 goes end of general support May 2014

Comment: Essentially, not even worth it if it's ESXi that he's trying to learn. If he just wants a virtual lab to play with guest machines, it will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please see detailed information on minimum requirements for VmWare ESX/ESXi OS below:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003661